# C# .contains() using Regular Expressions

Tags: c#, arrays, regex, wildcard

I'm currently trying to perform an array search which will return true if the array contains a string matches specific characters.

For example:

I have an array that contains these 3 values

```
"Atlanta Hawks are great this year!",
"Atlanta Braves are okay this year!",
"Atlanta Falcons are great this year!"
```

What I'm looking to do is to return true if the array contains at least one value matching the needle below...

```
"Atlanta* *are great this year!"
```

(Decided to use an asterisk as a wildcard in this example)

Which in this case would return true.

However for this array

```
"Atlanta Hawks are bad this year!",
"Detroit Tigers are okay this year!",
"New England Patriots are good this year!"
```

It would return false.

Currently what I'm doing is.. (and not working)

```
 if (result.Properties["memberOf"].Matches("Atlanta* *are great this year!"))
                {
                    return true;
                }
```

My question is, are there any wildcards that can be used with the .Contains() method or is there a similar method to the preg_grep() in PHP in C#?

I appreciate your help in advance.

Comment: You must use the `Regex` class to use regular expressions. `if (Regex.Matches(result.Properties["memberOf"], "Atlanta...."))`

Comment: And you would use the `IsMatch()` method for a `boolean` result. Also keep in mind that regular expressions use `.*` for "any number of any characters"

Answer (score 3):

I suggest converting *wild card* (with `*` and `?`) into a *regular expression* pattern and then using *Linq* to find out if there's `Any` item that matches the regular expression:

```
  string[] data = new string[] {
    "Atlanta Hawks are great this year!",
    "Atlanta Braves are okay this year!",
    "Atlanta Falcons are great this year!"
  };

  string wildCard = "Atlanta* *are great this year!";

  // * - match any symbol any times
  // ? - match any symbol just once
  string pattern = Regex.Escape(wildCard).Replace(@"\*", ".*").Replace(@"\?", ".");

  bool result = data.Any(item => Regex.IsMatch(item, pattern));
```

You may want to wrap the implementation into a method:

```
  private static bool ContainsWildCard(IEnumerable<String> data, String wildCard) {  
    string pattern = Regex.Escape(wildCard).Replace(@"\*", ".*").Replace(@"\?", ".");

    return data.Any(item => Regex.IsMatch(item, pattern));
  }

  ...

  String[] test = new String[] {
    "Atlanta Hawks are bad this year!",
    "Detroit Tigers are okay this year!",
    "New England Patriots are good this year!"
  }

  bool result = ContainsWildCard(test, "Atlanta* *are great this year!");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

```
string[] input = {"Atlanta Hawks are great this year!", "Atlanta Braves are okay this year!", "Atlanta Falcons are great this year!"};
var output = false;
Regex reg = new Regex("Atlanta (.*) are great this year!");
foreach (var item in input)
{        
    Match match = reg.Match(item);
    if (match.Success)
    {
        output = true;
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: For this tiny loop it won't matter, but generally it's best to avoid initializing a `new Regex` inside a loop. Better to declare it once and reuse it.

Comment: Is there a reason to keep checking after a match is found? You should probably break/return on match.Success.

Answer (score 0):

Don't have a compiler at hand, but it should be something like this:

```
public boolean checkMyArray(string[] theStringArray) {
    string pattern = "Atlanta (.*) are (great|okay) this year!";
    foreach (string s in theStringArray) {
       if(System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.IsMatch(s, pattern))
          return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```